# Hash Map entries collision

Tags: java, eclipse, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I am trying this code snippet

```
Map headers=new HashMap();
headers.put("X-Capillary-Relay","abcd");
headers.put("Message-ID","abcd");
```

Now when I do a `get` for either of the keys its working fine.
However I am seeing a strange phenomenon on the Eclipse debugger.
When I debug and go inside the Variables and check inside the `table` entry at first I see this

```
->table
--->[4]
------>key:X-Capillary-Relay
...........
```

However after debugging across the 2nd line I get

```
->table
--->[4]
------>key:Message-ID
...........
```

Instead of creating a new entry it overwrites on the existing key. For any other key this overwrite does not occur. The size of the map is shown 2. and the `get` works for both keys. So what is the reason behind this discrepancy in the eclipse debugger. Is it an eclipse problem? Or a hashing problem. The hashcode is different for the 2 keys.

Comment: As long as it works, there's no problem, or is there? The map won't have a separate bucket for each hash value, so no problem if both end up in the same bucket. Also I am pretty sure a new entry is created - how would you be able to retrieve both values from the map otherwise?

Comment: If code working and hashes are different but Eclipse debugger showing the map contents incorrectly then it would seem an issue with the debugger.

Comment: I suggest treating the HashMap as a black box - so long as you understand what it does, you don't need to understand how it does it. (BUT if you use ever objects as keys, DO implement hashCode() and equals())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hashCode` of the keys is not used as is.

It is applied two transformations (at least based on Java 6 code):

```
static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Returns index for hash code h.
 */
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

Since length is the initial capacity of the HashMap (16 by default), you get 4 for both keys :

```
System.out.println (hash("X-Capillary-Relay".hashCode ())&(16-1));
System.out.println (hash("Message-ID".hashCode ())&(16-1));
```

Therefore both entries are stored in a linked list in the same bucket of the map (index `4` of the `table` array, as you can see in the debugger). The fact that the debugger shows only one of them doesn't mean that the other was overwritten. It means that you see the key of the first Entry of the linked list, and each new Entry is added to the head of the list.